# = javascript_include_tag "application" giving error ExecJS::RuntimeError at / SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:1: unexpected //=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am more of a Java programmer and still somewhat new to development (2 years or so, can write Java code & web apps just fine) however the company I work for has 4 Rails applications and was asked to get this application working called CtrlPanel.  I have been having to learn Ruby on Rails in order to help get this issue with this app fixed and get it working.

I have been working on this problem for over a week all day long every day and nothing I do is fixing it.

I fixed everything to the point the app comes up, web server runs serves the pages but all views are white screens as long as this application.html.haml file is present.  I re-wrote the file with very basic bootstrap and it sort of works but nothing looks right.  The problem seems to stem from 1 single like that simply says:  = javascript_include_tag "application"

I have been all over the internet and have tried every single fix from changing coffee-script-source to v1.8.0 as I read Windows has an issue with newer rails and that file, I have tried every variation of changing it from application to default, and every type of ending you can think of no matter what I do it gives me this error message which I can not seem to find.

I am not even sure WHAT that line does, I assume it has to do with the new Google Maps API and I verified the key is valid and it was working before.

This is the error is it giving it says the line with "= javascript_include_tag" "application"
giving error
ExecJS::RuntimeError at / SyntaxError: [stdin]:1:1: unexpected //=

I am running a PC on Windows 10 20H2 x64 UEFI
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x64-mingw32]
Rails 6.1.3

(I did also install Ubuntu on another machine and it gives the exact same error, also gives the same error on another Windows machine)

The app is working IF I delete the "application.html.haml" file and put in a skeleton basic version all of the other views start working but of course none of them look right no menus no bootstrap no nothing.
Here is the application.html.haml file.

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title= full_title(yield(:title))
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all"
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "print", media: "print"
    = javascript_include_tag "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDOejvFkvPN_KP_9gnjH-Z8PB4eLtdju4E&libraries=geometry"
    = javascript_include_tag "application"
    = javascript_include_tag "//www.google.com/jsapi", "chartkick"
    = javascript_include_tag "http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    = csrf_meta_tags
    = render 'layouts/shim'
    %meta{:content => "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0", :name => "viewport"}

  %body
    = render 'layouts/header'
    .container-fluid.round.master
      - flash.each do |key, value|
        .alert-container
          .span6.offset3.alert-message.center{:class => "alert alert-#{key}"}
            = value
            %button.close#close-alert{"aria-hidden" => "true", "data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} ×
      = yield
      .spacer{style: "width:100%;margin-bottom:80px;"}
//      = render 'layouts/footer'
```

Here is my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby '2.7.2'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3'
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
#gem 'postgres_ext'  Breaks the app
gem 'paperclip'
#gem 'paperclip-aws'
#gem 'aws-sdk-v1'
gem 'haml'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
#gem 'bootstrap'
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'by_star'
gem 'simple_enum'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
# data dump
#gem 'yaml_db' - Gem is no longer supported and will NOT work with Rails 6 PERIOD.
# gem 'rb-readline'
# geocoding/addressing
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'gmaps-autocomplete-rails'
gem 'mechanize'
gem 'nikkou'

# caching
#gem 'memcachier'
#gem 'dalli'
#gem 'multi_fetch_fragments'
#gem 'cache_digests'

# Style and Appearance
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'chartkick'

#Forms and Input
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'ransack'
#gem 'protected_attributes' - No longer works with newer Rails Versions.
gem 'chronic'
gem 'protected_attributes_continued'
gem 'chosen-rails'

# Web Scraping
gem 'nokogiri'

# PDF Conversion
gem 'wicked_pdf'
#gem 'squeel', :git => "git://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel.git"

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
#gem 'unicorn'
gem 'puma'

# User Management
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'paper_trail'

# Content Control
gem 'browser'

# pdf creation
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-rails'
gem 'combine_pdf'

gem 'pry-byebug'

#Additional Gems required by Rails 6
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'letter_opener'
  #gem 'meta_request'
  #gem 'thin'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'erb2haml'

end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Here is the application.js file that I believe it is calling, even though the file is useless as it has nothing but commented lines in it.

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require gmaps-auto-complete
//= require timeago
//= require jquery.dataTables.min
//= require jquery.mark.min
//= require datatables.mark.min
//= require animate_numbers
//= require underscore-min
//= require gmaps/google
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require dealerships
//= require global
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

Screenshot of the error message:
[Error pointing to include tag application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ath1G.png)

I have also tried removing the "require_tree" . and about every other line in that file at one point or another and it appear to change nothing at all.  I have tried every version of changing the application word to default, again nothing seems to work.

If anyone needs to see anything else just let me know what, I am new to Ruby and Rails and I'm sure this is something I am missing I just don't know what and the Documentation doesn't seem to help.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank You,
Scott

Comment: While I understand the desire to release your frustrations, I would suggest this is not the appropriate forum. I would recommend pairing down this post to the actual issue at hand and remove your general job experience, your comparisons to Java, and your distaste of ruby and rails (remember you are asking us for help and the most helpful are those of us who enjoy this language). I certainly won't hold this post against you but a bit of decorum might be in order before I feel inclined to offer assistance.

Comment: Your right, my apologies, I updated the post...

Comment: Your post still has all the stuff that @engineersmnky said is irrelevant. And if a file only has comments in it, please do not post it here as it's not having any effect at all.

Comment: I would say at first glance the line that looks most suspect is `//      = render 'layouts/footer'`. Please try and remove the forward slashes from this line and report back. Also if you truly believe it is the application.js file have you tried removing just that line and see if there is still an error or if the error changes?

Comment: @engineersmnky  Thank you for the reply!     I removed the // with = render on it and the error is presisting, it is pointing to the line with the include tag application.  I just realized I didn't include the screenshot I had intended to keep with it, sorry for that.   In answer to your second question yes if I comment out the line with the include tag for application the program runs but I just get a white screen and if I inspect the HTML it is sending an incomplete HTML.

Comment: Continued.. file so I was assuming that include tag was necessary for something, I just haven't been able to figure out what it is or why its there.  I have seen in some other peoples tutorials for Ruby that the include tag with application seems to be in a lot of them,    I am trying to figure out how to add a screenshot in.

Comment: The file that has all comments gets changed at runtime to actually include the modules listed as //= required NameOfModule.  So while I thought it was irrelevant it was in fact VERY relevant but I didn't have any Rails knowledge at the time so I just didn't understand that.  Thought I would also mention this in case someone else is learning like myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally figure out what this was.
The older versions of rails in this case v4.2.1 used the javascript_include_tag for the line that deals with application:

= javascript_include_tag "application"

In the newer versions of rails in my case v6.1.3.1 you have to use javascript_pack_tag

= javascript_pack_tag

This solved the issue and the views all started working.  I did mention above I was working on a PC running Rails v6.1.3; however I noticed I didn't make it clear that I was also having to upgrade this program from Ruby v2.2.2 and Rails v4.2.1 to Ruby v 2.7.2 and Rails v6.1.3, that might have helped to have made that more clear.  Apologies if that confused anyone.  I am still VERY new to Rails and using StackOverflow.com.  I am happy to report I have only 1 single issue left on this program and the rest of the program is all working properly.  I will be posting another question in fact because the last issue deals with a complicated scope query and it uses different syntax again due to the newer version of rails and I haven't been able to figure it out.  In any even if you are running an older version of Rails and you are trying to get the program to work on a newer version (my case as I couldn't get rails v4.2 to run or work on ANYTHING, PC, Linux nothing) then you have to change the include_tag to a pack_tag.  I do not pretend to say I fully understand why.  I know it has to do with webpacker but beyond that I am still learning Rails.  Perhaps someone with more knowledge than myself can shed some insite as to why the syntax changed.  Oh and in addition the line ended up needing to read as follows:

= javascript_pack_tag     "application", "data-turbolinks-track": "reload"

I didn't have the turbolinks reference either.

I hope this helps someone else in a similar situation that I was in, it was not easy to find.  I only discovered it when I went through some tutorials on making other generic apps and saw the difference on that line.